# I can not install angular project: npm install -g @angular/cli

Tags: angular

I can not install angular project. when 'npm install -g @angular/cli' is complete but not create the folder or any file in project locations. How to install angular 6 projects on our computer? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyZ4W.png

Comment: seems like issue with node. npm. https://angular.io/guide/setup

Comment: You've installed it correctly. just do "ng new app1"

Comment: `ng new app1` followed by `cd app1` followed by `ng serve -o`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Steps 1 :Update the node with latest version and than execute the below command.**

**For updating the Angular CLI package ====>**

a)  npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli

b)  npm cache clean --force

c)  npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

d) npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli

e) npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest

Answer (score 0):

the npm command

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

doesn't create a new angular project but it globally installs *angular-cli* in your machine.
It looks like angular-cli has installed successfully in your machine.

Now ,you can create a new angular project using

```
ng new "project name"
```